# Why is transform:scale not kept on :hover?

Tags: css, transition

I am using this CSS:

```css
.link {
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
.link:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

When I hover the text, it's scaled to 110% as expected, but as soon as the transition is finished, it scales back to 100% even though the mouse pointer is still on the text.

When I remove the mouse pointer from the text, the animation scales to 110% then back to 100% in a flash.

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4dy4r89e/1/) for a demo.

**How can I make it keep the 110% scale until the pointer leaves the text?**

Comment: Note: this is the behaviour on Chrome. I just tested it in IE11, and it seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to define a link as `display: inline-block`, and add prefixes.
CSS:

```
.link {
    display: inline-block;
}

.link:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/4dy4r89e/2/)

Comment: `display: inline-block` is indeed the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Can you use Jquery ?

```
$(".link").hover(function(){ ... });
```

or maybe

```
$(".link").mouseover(function(){ ... });
```

Comment: Using jQuery to solve such a simple problem is overkill.