# CSS - Transform function not working on links?

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I did like so when a href's extension is .pdf; .doc; .ppt; .xls then it'll add corresponding file picture in front of it. Then I tried making a link go smaller when I hover over it but I doesn't do anything! Am I doing something wrong or what?

[image]

**Code:**

```css
ul{
  list-style-type: none;
}
ul a{
  text-decoration:none;
  padding-left: 20px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
ul a:hover{
  text-decoration:underline;
  color:#666;
  -moz-transform: scale(0.9);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.9);
  transform: scale(0.9);
}
a[href$=".pdf"]{
  background-image:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJlYq.gif);
}
a[href$=".doc"]{
  background-image:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2lbW.gif);
}
a[href$=".ppt"]{
  background-image:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tk5Vv.gif);
}
a[href$=".xls"]{
  background-image:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOr7E.gif);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="/one.pdf">pdf</a></li>
  <li><a href="/two.doc">doc</a></li>
  <li><a href="/three.ppt">ppt</a></li>
  <li><a href="/four.xls">xls</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30483787/why-is-transformscale-not-kept-on-hover

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use `display: inline-block` for `<a>` tag (or `display: block`), because `<a>` has `display: inline` by default, but [transformable element](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms/#transformable-element) can't be with `display: inline`:

> [Transformable element](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms/#transformable-element) — an element whose layout is governed by the CSS box model which is either a block-level or atomic inline-level element, or ...
>
> [Inline-block](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-display) — this value causes an element to generate an inline-level block container. The inside of an inline-block is formatted as a block box, and the element itself is formatted as an atomic inline-level box.

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

ul a {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-left: 20px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
}

ul a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #666;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.9);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.9);
    transform: scale(0.9);
}

a[href $= '.pdf'] {
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJlYq.gif);
}

a[href $= '.doc'] {
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2lbW.gif);
}

a[href $= '.ppt'] {
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tk5Vv.gif);
}

a[href $= '.xls'] {
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOr7E.gif);
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="/one.pdf">pdf</a></li>
    <li><a href="/two.doc">doc</a></li>
    <li><a href="/three.ppt">ppt</a></li>
    <li><a href="/four.xls">xls</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Accepted, sorry i'm new to this Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4):

`transform` is not applicable to inline elements such as `<a>`. You could display the link as inline-block or block to get transform to work!

> transformable element
>   A transformable element is an element in one of these categories:
>
> - an element whose layout is governed by the CSS box model which is either a block-level or atomic inline-level element, or whose display property computes to table-row, table-row-group, table-header-group, table-footer-group, table-cell, or table-caption [CSS21]
> - an element in the SVG namespace and not governed by the CSS box model which has the attributes transform, ‘patternTransform‘ or gradientTransform [SVG11].
>
> http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/#transformable-element
>   http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/#transform-property

**This code is working:**

```css
ul{
  list-style-type: none;
}
ul a{
  display:inline-block;
  text-decoration:none;
  padding-left: 20px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
ul a:hover{
  display:inline-block;
  text-decoration:underline;
  color:#666;
  -moz-transform: scale(0.9);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.9);
  transform: scale(0.9);
}
a[href$=".pdf"]{
  background-image:url(http://placehold.it/20x20);
}
a[href$=".doc"]{
  background-image:url(http://placehold.it/20x20);
}
a[href$=".ppt"]{
  background-image:url(http://placehold.it/20x20);
}
a[href$=".xls"]{
  background-image:url(http://placehold.it/20x20);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="/one.pdf">pdf</a></li>
  <li><a href="/two.doc">doc</a></li>
  <li><a href="/three.ppt">ppt</a></li>
  <li><a href="/four.xls">xls</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put `display: inline-block` on the link elements. You can't seem to transform inline elements. Also - your syntax should be perfectly valid, though you likely have too many prefixes. Only IE9 should need the MS prefix, I'd doubt any others would be needed.