# transform: translateX makes hyperlink unclickable

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made a carousel slider(copied the code from some codepen then made some changes) and it looks something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNBpC.png). Anyway the problem is that those images have hyperlinks that work unless i make a transform on x axis..for lets say 240px the hyperlinks stops working. What i mean by that its that its unclickable.
This is the structure of the html [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isp0E.png).
I made a script that adds `style = "transform:translateX(-240px);` to the carousel div.

Expected behaviour: the hyperlink should pe clickable.

You can find the code at: https://github.com/AlexxW/AlexxW.github.io
and the webpage at https://watchwhatmovie.tk/ (for some reason its not updated yet)

Answer (score 1):

Try posting code instead of images for better answers.

this question similar to -  [CSS - Transform function not working on links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34710090/css-transform-function-not-working-on-links/34710222)

you need to make the link (i.e `<a>` tag) CSS to `display: block;` because transform doesn't work on `display: inline;` (which is default for a tag).

Comment: Thank you for your answear, I edited the question and added a github repo.

Answer (score 0):

Because no css was provided, maybe the z-index is not correct (the layers). Try this:

```
.card {
    position: /* set this to relative/absolute, depending on your preference */;
    z-index: 1;
}
```